# How to capture response tags when we use the websocket single read sampler JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter

How to capture all the response tags when we use the websocket single read sampler JMeter. I tried to use Regular Expression extractor but it is capturing only last response. But i want to capture tags in all the responses

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're actually capturing all responses, but your Debug Sampler placement is not correct so it is being executed once when you exit your "Read Data Loop" hence it's displaying only last value.

Move it inside the "Read Data Loop" and you will see all the values. See [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more details.

Few more hints:

- It seems that you're getting responses in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format so it makes sense to migrate to [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- You might want to declare your variable as the [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables), this way you will get the values added to the .[jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and even plot them as a [custom chart in the HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)